Icon categories in the start menu. What entry is responsible for the category?
What entry in the *.desktop ($HOME/.local/share/applications/app.desktop) file is required for an icon to be assigned to the appropriate category in the KDE menu?
I would like to do it using a Bash script, so using the KMenuEdit application is not enough for me.
All the icons I create end up in Lost and Found.

This is specified in the Desktop Entry Specification. The entry relevant to your question is Categories. Categories are listed here.

Thanks for the help! :)
